# multiple output from a list of data frames

Tags: r

I'm trying to get all five outputs from the 5 data frames within the list x at the same time, but I am stuck here. Also, if i want the function to return specific coefficient from each output, say `X24hr_PM25`, what to do? THANKS!

Here is the code:

```
q1<-cvd[cvd$quintile=='1',]
q2<-cvd[cvd$quintile=='2',]
q3<-cvd[cvd$quintile=='3',]
q4<-cvd[cvd$quintile=='4',]
q5<-cvd[cvd$quintile=='5',]

x<-list(q1,q2,q3,q4,q5)

analyze <- function(data, df) {
  for (i in 1:length(data)) {
    fit <- glm(cvd_o ~ X24hr_PM25 + ns(c7, 6*df) + ns(temp, 4) + ns(rh, 4) + dow,
               family=poisson, data=as.data.frame(data[i]))
    sum <- summary(fit)
    return(sum)
  }
}
```

Comment: You want `data[[i]]`, not `data[i]`. The latter is a list of length 1, the former is the contents of that list.

Comment: Also, `return` will make the function call exit after processing the first iteration of the `for` loop... Also, what is `df`? Try to make your code reproducible by giving us everything.